# remove elements from a list that begin with a specific character

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove all mentions of anyone from a string, I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this?

```
text = "hey @foo say hi to @bar"
textsplit = text.split()
n = -1
ts2 = textsplit
for x in textsplit:
    n += 1
    if x[0]== "@":
        del ts2[n]
text = ' '.join(ts2)
```

Thanks in advance. (This is sort of like [Removing elements from a list containing specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416401/removing-elements-from-a-list-containing-specific-characters) but this one is a little different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the same as your code:

```
' '.join(x for x in text.split() if not x.startswith('@'))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one, using re module and regular expression:

```
print(" ".join(re.sub('^@\w+', '', w) for w in text.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler and faster:

```
text = "hey @foo say hi to @bar"
newtext = ' '.join([i for i in text.split() if not i.startswith('@')])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "hey @foo say hi to @bar"
newtext = re.sub(' @[!\w]+', '', text)
```

No need to use any loops, simply use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I defer to @elyase and @chris-johnson's answers for the actual simple beautiful code that you should use.

@elyase's answer is simpler, but I think @chris-johnson's might be slightly more efficient because of how `join` works.  @elyase's code creates a generator object, then `join` will convert it into a list before running, which I believe has more overhead than just creating a list to begin with.  But this is a minor optimization point.

I just identified a few code smells in your sample code, so want to point them out.

```
text = "hey @foo say hi to @bar"
textsplit = text.split()
n = -1
ts2 = textsplit # code smell 1
for x in textsplit:
    n += 1 # code smell 2
    if x[0]== "@":
        del ts2[n] # code smell 3
text = ' '.join(ts2)
```

**Code smell 1**: I imagine you want to create a copy of a list with `ts2 = textsplit`, but this isn't happening.  You're just creating another name for the list that `textsplit` refers to, so changing `ts2` will change `textsplit` and viceversa.  You can do `ts2 = textsplit[:]` to make a copy of a non-nested list.

**Code smell 2**: You're creating a variable `n` and using that as the index by manually incrementing at each iteration.  If that's all you're doing, use `for n, x in enumerate(textsplit)` instead.

**Code smell 3**: Two things here:

1. Because you didn't copy textsplit, you're looping over a list and modifying it at once - avoid this at all costs, it causes bugs that are insanely hard to reason about.
2. Even if ts2 were a copy, this row is problematic because when you delete an element in ts2, the index gets thrown out of sync.  In your example, after deleting '@foo', the indices are now off by one, so trying to access/delete '@bar' using `ts2[n]` will throw an IndexError.  If you are going to engage in index twiddling, you need to decrement `n` every time you delete an item.

But generally, index twiddling is a source of many many bugs.  Don't do it if you don't have to.  And in Python you often don't have to.

Comment: Woah thanks for explaining, I learned some new things from that, I will be sure to remember this next time!

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that all the other answers are operating under the assumption that you wish to remove the `@...` substring and maintain a separation of `' '` between different words (or sets of characters other than `' '`), as evidenced by your code. However, the question does not otherwise explicity point this as the objective. And, since there could potentially be a situation when (don't ask me) this behaviour isn't the correct one, here we go!

**Edit:** Readable and flexible now (vs old code-golfy versions)

My original post was a bit silly in that the code really wasn't meant for production; it worked, but that was it. This now accomplishes three types of substring substractions effortlessly, although perhaps it could be done better with regular expressions (not too experienced there).

```
text = "hey @foo say hi to @bar"
```

#### Regular version with only a single `' '` to separate the remaining words

```
newText = ''.join(
    text[i] if text.rfind('@', 0, i+2) <= text.rfind(' ', 0, i+1) else
    '' for i in xrange(len(text)))

>>> 'hey say hi to'
```

#### Removes only the specified substring (without removing any other whitespace)

```
newText = ''.join(
    text[i] if text.rfind('@', 0, i+1) <= text.rfind(' ', 0, i+1) else
    '' for i in xrange(len(text)))

>>> 'hey  say hi to '
```

#### Transforms the substring into whitespace

```
newText = ''.join(
    text[i] if text.rfind('@', 0, i+1) <= text.rfind(' ', 0, i+1) else
    ' ' for i in xrange(len(text)))

>>> 'hey      say hi to     '
```

Hope this helps, somehow!