# Remove item from a list element?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

This may seem odd, but I am trying to remove a part of an item contained in a list. Basically, I am trying to remove a specific character from multiple list elements. For example

```
list = ['c1','c2','c3','d1','s1']
list.remove('c')
```

I know that doing that wouldn't work, but is there any way to remove the "c"s in the list, and only the "c"s in Python 3?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = [s.replace('c','') for s in lst]
# ['1','2','3','d1','s1']
```

List comprehensions are your friend. Also note the "list" is a keyword in Python, so I highly recommend you *do not* use it as a variable name.

Comment: The variable list was an example. This was not meant to be functional Python code. But thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions,

```
list = ['c1','c2','c3','d1','s1']

list_ = [ x for x in list if "c" not in x ]  # removes elements which has "c"
print list_  # ['d1', 's1']
```

Comment: Ah. Didn't think of this interpretation of the question, this could very well be what the asker is looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['c1','c2','c3','d1','d2']

list2 = []

for i in range (len(list1)):
    if 'c' not in list1[i]:
        list2.append(list1[i])

print (list2) #['d1', 'd2']
```

and also this link may helpful

[Link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416401/removing-elements-from-a-list-containing-specific-characters)