# How can I isolate a certain string from a list in all instances in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a quite large list with lots of not needed information and only a certain word string that I want. So if I had a list of:

```
my_list = ["cookies are good", "cookies are bad", "cookies are very good"]
```

And I wanted to cut everything out except all instances of good in a segment so it would look like this:

```
my_list = ["cookies are good", "cookies are very good"]
```

How could I do this? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements from a list containing specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416401/removing-elements-from-a-list-containing-specific-characters)

Comment: `[i for i in my_list if "good" in i]`

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension solves this problem:

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if 'good' in x]
```