# how to remove an item from a list in python if that item contains a word

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list

```
a = ['https://example.co/embed/qACAB6TukkU/The.Ha-az.VOST.WEBRip.XviD-ZT.W.avi',
     'https://example.co/embed/l31lsZilT2E/The.Ha-az-ndmaids.FR.HDTV.XviD-ZT.W.avi',
     'https://example.com/embed/soslnnqnmccmplfa/The_Ha-az02_VOST_WEBRip_XviD-ZT_W_avi',
     'https://example.com/embed/pffpmptfpdfqddap/The_Ha-az-_Tale_S2_FRENCH_HDTV_XviD-ZT_W_avi']
```

I want to remove every item in that list that contain word "VOST" in the link. This what I know and what I have tried:

```
a.remove('VOST')
print a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements from a list containing specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416401/removing-elements-from-a-list-containing-specific-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try iterating through each item and filtering it using `list comprehension`:

```
filtered = [i for i in a if 'VOST' not in i]
```

The above code is similar and better way to following:

```
filtered = []
for i in a:
    if 'VOST' not in i:
        filtered.append(i)
```

---

If you want to use `remove`, you can iterate through each item and check if word to look for is in item and then remove item. You can try the code below:

**Note**: *This will remove the item from original list, the previous answer creates new list named* `filtered`:

```
for i in a:
    if 'VOST' in i:
        a.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner but I don’t think it will work to use a.remove, since removing an item from the list will screw up the indexing for future items. It’s a better solution to create a new list and append items that don’t contain ‘VOST’.

Comment: One actually can remove items in place - see my answer. You just need to iterate in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to remove items *in-place* then the following might work for you:

```
for i in [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if 'VOST' in v][::-1]:
    del a[i]
```

Alternatively,

```
for i in reversed([i for i, v in enumerate(a) if 'VOST' in v]):
    del a[i]
```

or,

```
for i in reversed(range(len(a))):
    if 'VOST' in a[i]:
        del a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
filter(lambda x: "VOST" not in x, a)
```